# Selection Sort with output issue

Tags: java, data-structures

I have problem with output of this selection sort>>the output shows set of followed zero then the correct answer>> how to eliminate these zero??

```
package lap;

import java.util.Scanner;

  public class MySelectionSort {

    public static int[] doSelectionSort(int[] arr){

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
                if (arr[j] < arr[index]) 
                    index = j;

            int smallerNumber = arr[index];  
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        int []A=new int[100];
        int N; 
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" enter array size");
        N=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" enter array elments");

        for (int i=0; i<N;i++){
           A[i]=scan.nextInt();    
        }
        // int[] arr1 = {10,34,2,56,7,67,88,42};
        int[] arr2 = doSelectionSort(A);
        for( int i=0;i<arr2.length;i++){
            System.out.print(arr2[i]);
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `int []A=new int[100];` with array size `N` and not `100`. That will resolve the issue. So essentially you initialized the array of elements to 100 whereas you are going to have `N` elements in you array, which is a user provided value.

So the updated code would be:

```
public static void main(String a[]){
    int N;
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(" enter array size");
    N=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print(" enter array elments");
    int []A=new int[N];
    .....
    .....
```

Comment: I appreciate for you sir, but how to eliminate duplication from output??